# Do summoning spells target the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Many spells have a range of self, in which case [the caster is a target](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71791/do-spells-with-a-range-of-self-target-the-caster).

However, summoning spells don't have a range of self, but nonetheless have some sort of effect on the caster, in that they are now being obeyed by the summoned creature(s).

For example, the [Summon Greater Demon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) spell says the following:

> Roll initiative for the demon, which has its own turns. When you summon it and on each of your turns thereafter, you can issue a verbal command to it (requiring no action on your part), telling it what it must do on its next turn. If you issue no command, it spends its turn attacking any creature within reach that has attacked it.

Similarly, the [Conjure Animals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals) spell states:

> The summoned creatures are friendly to you and your companions. Roll initiative for the summoned creatures as a group, which has its own turns. They obey any verbal commands that you issue to them (no action required by you).

Do these spells "target" the caster?

Comment: Related: [What counts as a target for a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152115/what-counts-as-a-target-for-a-spell)

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: "[What does the Find Familiar spell target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152373)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

They target “a space that you can see” within range. They affect both you and the summoned creature(s) but they target neither.

Comment: You said, "They effect both you and the summoned creature(s) but they target neither." Isn't "been affected" by the spell sufficient to be "targeted" by it? Jeremy Crawford clarified in the 19/JAN/2017 Sage Advice segment of the Dragon Talk podcast: "any time a spell is telling you to pick a creature or an object or a point in space, to be affected by something, really that thing is functioning in that moment as a target of some kind."

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Add it to the long list of things he’s wrong about

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I will point out that summoning spells don't tell you to pick yourself. And also state that spell targeting is one of the most rules-complicated bits of 5e; we have a *lot* of questions on what counts as a target in general or for a specific spell and there's little consistency

Comment: I think JC's comment is generally correct but it's possible to go overboard with it. Command over a creature is not being a target of the spell, it's being the caster. The target is the thing being created, damaged, or whatever.  The point of his discussion is that if the spell says you hit one creature and then deal damage in an area around it, then any creature in that area is also a target, or if the spell damages an enemy and then heals you, you're a target. It's not making the caster a "target" every time he shoots a beam from a fingertip or issues orders to a dominated enemy.